# Storyboard and AutoLayout: how to set UIView to use same aspect ratio as device?

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout, storyboard

With Storyboard and AutoLayout constraints, is there a way to make a UIView use the same aspect ratio as the device?

Or is the only option to manually specify this in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UIView in UIViewController has always the same ratio.
Unrelated to a UIViewController you need to determine the screen you want to relate to. (There can be more than 1 during run time)

```
UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.screen.bounds
```

would give you the bounds of the first window during runtime.

Autolayout in this case requires a view you can relate to.

You could have a same width and height constraint on your view and the topmostview. (Superview)